# How to change font of menubar in tkinter python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()
window.geometry("%dx%d" % (10, 10))
window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
window.title("Snap")
Font=f.Font(family='Courier 10')
menubar = Menu(window)
File = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0,font=Font)
File.add_command(label="New",font=Font) 
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=File,font=Font)

window.config(menu=menubar)
window.mainloop()
```

This's an example code. My question is how to change font of menubar. I use this code to change but it doesn't work.

Comment: What platform are you running on? I would be surprised if windows or OSX would support doing this.

Comment: I using window 10

Comment: You are not initializing the Font object properly so it uses the default font (try looking at `Font.actual()` to get the properties).  It should be either `Font=f.Font(font='Courier 10')` or `Font=f.Font(family='Courier', size=10)`. Doing that, it works in Linux but Bryan has a point, there might be OS specific limitations.